# DHCP server provides multiple routers - why some clients don't use them all?

Tags: routing, dhcp, router, gateway

In a LAN of ~100 hosts we have a DHCP server (ISC DHCP), and we have two LAN-WAN gateways (in the same subnet) to provide redundancy in case one gateway fails. DHCP server is configured to provide addresses of both gateways:

```
option routers 192.168.0.1, 192.168.0.3;
```

Now, on sompe DHCP clients the `ip route` yields:

```
default via 192.168.0.1 dev enp7s0 proto dhcp metric 100 
default via 192.168.0.3 dev enp7s0 proto dhcp metric 101 
192.168.0.0/24 dev enp7s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.109 metric 100
```

i.e., both gateways are present in the routing table. However, on some others clients, the second gateway is completely ignored:

```
default via 192.168.0.1 dev eno2 proto dhcp src 192.168.0.14 metric 100 
192.168.0.0/24 dev eno2 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.14 
192.168.0.1 dev eno2 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.0.14 metric 100
```

There is no obvious reason to differentiate between the two cases, although the majority of hosts that ignore the second gateway run under Ubuntu Server 20.04, while majority of hosts that do not ignore it run under Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 or Arch Linux.

Is it possible to achive a server-only configuration such that all clients (including MS Window hosts and mobiles) use both routers in the routing tables? Or does this indeed depend on client-side configuration?

Comment: Because they can't. In Linux, there are several DHCP client implementations, they not are all equal. Some might just not support this feature; some may have it disabled. Please, check, which DHCP clients exaclty are used, you'll certainly will find a correlation. As to last sentence, why you need this? This is not a proper way to do, say, high availability, it won't work the way you expected.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So this behavior depends on clients, indeed. Then, what mechanism would you suggest for gateway failover, for a small to medium sized LAN? I've read about VRRP, and how it can be implemented using Ubuntu Server, but I don't quite understand - in this case the access to WAN again depends on a single machine (which runs `keepalived`), so the whole point of the failover setup is lost (unless I misunderstand something).

Comment: Dual gateway in DHCP doesn't provide failover, but VRRP *is* a proper solution. Yes, it seems you misunderstand something. In short, you'd run keepalived on both hosts, they communicate and a slave keepalived will decide to become a master and claim a floating IP if it doesn't have messages from the running keepalived on the other host. That (single) floating IP is the address you set in the DHCP as a gateway.

Comment: Many thanks, will have a deeper look at VRRP.